# USB mic inbuilt with WebCam not giving any inputs

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, microphone, webcam

I have a Web-Cam with a microphone in-built and the company claims that, it is 'plug-to-play' (Don't need any driver installation - according to me). When I plug the web-cam, it works well, and also the mic will also show up in `device manager` [image from 'device manager ' - Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5pCg.png)

But it is not giving any inputs. And the webcam I use don't have an separate wire for the mic, it is just one USB cable for both webcam and microphone

Comment: Check Windows privacy settings. There you can enable/disable audio input/mic for for each Windows app individually and also for regular Windows applications.

Comment: Yeah, i checked that, it's all on. and other microphone works fine

Comment: Have you selected the USB microphone as primary audio input device in Windows audio settings? There is also a microphone test showing the signal level.

Comment: can you help me to do that pls?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the settings under your sound devices. The way you access this menu can vary depending on your version of Windows 10 so I've given a slightly longer approach to access it but should mean you can get there without issue.

1. Click on Start
2. Type in control panel and open it
3. You should have an option that says "Hardware and Sound" click on this (if not look for just Sound)
4. Click on Recording at the top

You are now in the Sound settings and from here you have a few options to test things. The first thing I would do is look for the device in this list. On the right hand side there is an indicator that will respond to sounds. Make a loud noise and see if the computer recognizes it (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1s1K.png)). If you do not see that indicator on your device it generally means that the device is disabled. You can enable it by right clicking and clicking enable.

If you are seeing a reaction to sound the next thing you should do is make sure that it is your default device and default communication device. You can do this by clicking on it so that it is highlighted and then checking at the bottom to see if the Set Default option is available. If you can, use Set Default to set it as both your default device and default communication device. (If this was the problem then I would recommend testing it with whatever software you are trying to use it for. It may be necessary to restart either the software or your computer for the changes to fully take effect.)

If you're seeing a reaction, its set as the default device and default communication device but it is still not working then I would next recommend clicking on Properties. This will open a new window and at the top you should have an option that says Levels. Click on this and slide the volume slider up and test everything again. This effects how loud your microphone is.

If you've checked everything here and it all seems to be working correctly than the issue maybe with whatever software you are using. The most likely issue is that its trying to use a different recording device that your computer has or thinks it has. The easiest solution to this is to disable any other recording devices other than the one from your web cam.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thankks! but it is is max all the time, while not giving any input as in the [image](https://i.imgur.com/FjmP6IS.png)